# My plugin not updating properly (issue with upgrader_process_complete)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have users who have installed my plugin (we'll call it v6).

V6 version of my plugin does not register a handler for `upgrader_process_complete`.

In my new version, I have `upgrader_process_complete` registered to do some upgrades to my database table.

However, it seems that when the user upgrades from the Plugins page using the `update now` link, the handler of my new version is not invoked.

Could anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: If you install your plugin new (not update) starts the action hook?

Comment: I have a listener registered to  `'init'` and am also doing `register_activation_hook` so if the plugin is deactivate/reactivate, the upgrade script runs fine. It also runs fine with a new install (from the WP.org or zip file).

Comment: @Gezim Did you figure this out? I'm trying to test the `upgrader_process_complete` hook myself, but not sure how without updating my plugin in the repo. I have `register_activation_hook` working, but not sure if the function is firing for both.

Comment: @BenbodhiMantra I have not! I had same issue. I think I just opted for `init` hook and do the install there which gets called all the time but .. didn't find a good alternative. I wrote a little plugin to emulate the update but not sure if it'll work: https://github.com/hgezim/dev-plugin-test

Comment: Thanks @Gezim, I'll have a dig and see how I go. I also tested with [GitHub Updater](https://github.com/afragen/github-updater) plugin which requires an added line to my own plugin header and then it can check a GitHub repo for updates... So I could test without updating the WordPress repo. But unfortunately my hook into `upgrader_process_complete` was not working on last try. I decided to give it a few days to clear my head of all the work I was doing, possibly confusing myself too easily.

Answer (score 2):

The `upgrader_process_complete` hook is running in the current version while updating the plugin.

---

Let say that you are running plugin v 6.0.
And then you are just updated to 6.1 which contain `upgrader_process_complete` hook in this version.
The upgrader hook will not be called until next scenario.

Now you have running plugin v 6.1 which contain `upgrader_process_complete` hook since v 6.1.
And you are just updated to 6.2 which contain the code that write **ABC.txt** file.
The upgrader hook for 6.1 will be called, NOT 6.2. So, it means that the **ABC.txt** file will not be created.

If you are running plugin v 6.1 and want to run the newly updated code from 6.2 that just updated, you have to add something like transient to get notice that the update from new version of code is need.
And here is from my plugin. You can use as you need under MIT license.

---

```
<?php

class Upgrader
{


        /**
         * Display link or maybe redirect to manual update page.
         * 
         * To understand more about new version of code, please read more on `updateProcessComplete()` method.
         * 
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices Reference.
         */
        public function redirectToUpdatePlugin()
        {
            if (get_transient('myplugin_updated') && current_user_can('update_plugins')) {
                // if there is updated transient
                // any background update process can be run here.
                // write your new version of code that will be run after updated the plugin here.
            }// endif;
        }// redirectToUpdatePlugin


        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public function registerHooks()
        {
            // on update/upgrade plugin completed. set transient and let `redirectToUpdatePlugin()` work.
            add_action('upgrader_process_complete', [$this, 'updateProcessComplete'], 10, 2);
            // on plugins loaded, background update the plugin with new version.
            add_action('plugins_loaded', [$this, 'redirectToUpdatePlugin']);
        }// registerHooks


        /**
         * After update plugin completed.
         * 
         * This method will be called while running the current version of this plugin, not the new one that just updated.
         * For example: You are running 1.0 and just updated to 2.0. The 2.0 version will not working here yet but 1.0 is working.
         * So, any code here will not work as the new version. Please be aware!
         * 
         * This method will add the transient to work again and will be called in `redirectToUpdatePlugin()` method.
         * 
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/ Reference.
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete Reference.
         * @param \WP_Upgrader $upgrader
         * @param array $hook_extra
         */
        public function updateProcessComplete(\WP_Upgrader $upgrader, array $hook_extra)
        {
            if (is_array($hook_extra) && array_key_exists('action', $hook_extra) && array_key_exists('type', $hook_extra) && array_key_exists('plugins', $hook_extra)) {
                if ($hook_extra['action'] == 'update' && $hook_extra['type'] == 'plugin' && is_array($hook_extra['plugins']) && !empty($hook_extra['plugins'])) {
                    $this_plugin = plugin_basename(MYPLUGIN_FILE);// MYPLUGIN_FILE is come from __FILE__ of the main plugin file.
                    foreach ($hook_extra['plugins'] as $key => $plugin) {
                        if ($this_plugin == $plugin) {
                            // if this plugin is in the updated plugins.
                            // set transient to let it run later. this transient will be called and run in `redirectToUpdatePlugin()` method.
                            set_transient('myplugin_updated', 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }// endforeach;
                    unset($key, $plugin, $this_plugin);
                }// endif update plugin and plugins not empty.
            }// endif; $hook_extra
        }// updateProcessComplete


    }
```

Please carefully read and modify the code above.
In your plugin file, call to `Upgrader->registerHooks()` method.
And write your code inside `redirectToUpdatePlugin()` method to work as background update process.

---

From my code, the procedure will be like this...
Running plugin v 6.0 -> update to 6.1 -> The code in 6.0 set transient that it is just updated.
Reload the page or click to anywhere in admin pages. -> Now v 6.1 is running. -> On the plugin loaded hook, it can detected that this plugin is just updated. -> Call to `redirectToUpdatePlugin()` method and background process start working here.

Comment: How is this answering op ? Already v6.0 is running. How am i going to add set_transient in that version ?