# Update hook in wordpress not fired

Tags: wordpress

I want to perform a database operation on plugin update. My current version of plugin doesn't have this hook. I added the following code in the updated version. I am using the following code, but this doesn't work.

```
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'init_plugin_update', 10, 2 );
function init_plugin_update( $upgrader_object, $options ) {
    error_log('test123');
}
```

I have seen WooCommerce using the same hook. So is there something i am unaware of ? Won't the new plugin file get loaded before this action ?

Comment: are you manually updating plugin or auto update

Comment: Manually updating using update now link in plugins admin page

Comment: I have tested this and it works! Where did you put the add_action()?

Comment: I have added this is in the main plugin file. Suppose i have version 2.0 with me. I added this code in 3.0. When i update plugin from 2.0 to 3.0, this code is not executed. Some sources say that, only the old plugin file will be executed when updating. Codes in 3.0 will only be executed when updating 3.0 to greater versions

Comment: I don't think that is correct. My question really is how are you executing the add_action(), i.e., are you sure the add_action() call itself was executed? I know that this does work so there must be something different in the way you are doing it. Can you do an error_log( 'add_action() done' ) after the add action?

Comment: The `add_action` is not called. I added the code in the main plugin file (plugin_name.php) I have searched a lot and the only valid comment was https://stackoverflow.com/a/50914655/8913606

Comment: If the call to add_action() is not done then of course it doesn't work. I cannot solve this with the information you have provided. Can you provide the complete context in which the call to add_action() is suppose to be made. You have a more fundamental problem than the article referred to as your add_action() is never called. The first step here is to get the add action() to execute. In the worse case you can put it at the very top of your plugin code. It would be ugly there but it should get called.

Comment: @MagentaCuda I have added the code at the top of plugin file. It is not called.

Comment: Without knowing the context it is too difficult to help you. I cannot be sure but I think you are doing something wrong because (1) This hook does work for a plugin I use. (2) I read the source code and the hook you are using seems to execute unconditionally - see ".../wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php" around line 835. This hook is also done elsewhere but for your case - "using update now link in plugins admin page" - I think this is the correct location. Sorry, but I am giving up. Good Luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [upgrader_process_complete](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/upgrader_process_complete/) hook, as it's stated in the Codex:

> Fires when the upgrader process is complete.

But it's also stated in the Notes:

> Use with caution: When you use the upgrader_process_complete action hook in your plugin and your plugin is the one which under upgrade, then this action will run the old version of your plugin.

Effectively it means, if your current version of the plugin is 1.0 and it doesn't have this hook, and you're updating the plugin to version 2.0 which has that hook - it won't get fired.

**Further Problems with this and other hooks**

To perform a database upgrade (in case your version 2.0 has a different table structure) you obviously can't use this hook.

There is another scenario - when your plugin is updated via FTP and not the admin interface (for example you push some file changes through GIT CI/CD pipelines) - none of the hooks will get fired.

**The solution**

Manually manage the database version of your plugin.

1. Save the current plugin version in the database with
   [add_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/).
2. On [init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) hook (or even better, on
   [admin_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/) hook, because it gets triggered only during an admin
   request - the Core uses this technique) perform a check if the
   current version of the plugin is equal as the saved version in the
   database. Use [get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) and compare that with the version hardcoded in the plugin itself
3. If there's a mismatch, that means that the database runs
   off of the old codebase and you need to update it

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using different admin hooks to solve this problem

Comment: Care to tell which hook you used? We have a similar case where our code deploys through git; this hook does not triggers at all. So we are contemplating to use the path mentioned by dev_masta.